# Best way to write global method in asp.net mvc 4 which can be accessed though any view in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing web application in asp.net mvc 4 which supports multi-languages. All resources keys/values are stored in database table. **I want to write global method which can be accessible in any view throughout my application.** This global method takes data from database and put it in cache as user request. If user requested resource key is present in cache then it returns it else first it will query database put that resource value in cache and return that value to display in view. I want to access it from view like

```
@MessageInUserLanguage(ResourceKey,LanguageID)
```

Where should I write this method and what is best way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you accept any alternatives (like `@Html.SomeMethod(...)` )? It may be way too hard to achieve `@MessageInUserLanguage`. Maybe after Razor accepts C# 6.0 syntax for global methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static class with static method should be fine:

```
public static class SharedLogic
{
    public static string MessageInUserLanguage(
        string ResourceKey, 
        string LanguageID) 
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
```

In your view(s) you may call it like below:

```
@SharedLogic.MessageInUserLanguage("resKey", "LangID")
```

You may keep it in the same assembly with your views or in separate one.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you said I created one static class with static method at root level folder. But I need to manually put using MyApp.SharedLogic in my view then only I get access to this static method. Is there any way to import it other way? I try to put using MyApp.SharedLogic in my _Layout.cshtml page so that it will accessible to all my views but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about class name in method invocation(edited). You could add the namespace that you want to import by default for all views in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` -> `<pages>` -> `<namespaces>` section of Web.config(located in `Views` folder) ...

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method for the `HtmlHelper` class:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MessageInUserLanguage(this HtmlHelper helper, string resourceKey, string laguageId)
    {
        // todo..
        return new HtmlString("");
    }
}
```

You can call it in your view like this (as you probably already knew):

```
@Html.MessageInUserLanguage("test", "test");
```

What's nice about this approach is that the [`HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class gives you access to several useful properties such as `ViewContext`, which contains `HttpContext`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class SharedLogic
{
    public static string MessageInUserLanguage(
        string ResourceKey, 
        string LanguageID) 
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}public static class SharedLogic
{
    public static string MessageInUserLanguage(
        string ResourceKey, 
        string LanguageID) 
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}public static class SharedLogic
{
    public static string MessageInUserLanguage(
        string ResourceKey, 
        string LanguageID) 
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
        string ResourceKey, 
        string LanguageID) 
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add some explanation to it in plain English. It also looks like you are repeating the content.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but rather some random code